# read_excel() yields an error when trying to load one file

Tags: r, excel

I am trying to load in the following `.xls` file.

Link to `.xls` file.
https://ufile.io/5vy4g

I am using a function (which I have cut down to the necessity.

```
product <- c("/saltsnck")

gettables <- function(year, weeks, product){
prod <- read_excel("E:/DIR/prod_saltsnck.xls")
}

Map(gettables, year, weeks, product)
```

The `DIR` will need to be changed to the `DIR` the file is downloaded to. The file is called `prod_saltsnck.xls`.

When I try to load in the file I get the following error:

```
 Error in read_fun(path = path, sheet_i = sheet, limits = limits, shim = shim,  : 
      Failed to open E:DIR/prod_saltsnck.xls
```

When looking online some suggestions point towards the sheet name being incorrect but this file is the same as many other similar files I am loading into R. The only difference being that it is a different product.

When I directly try to read in the file outside the function I get the same error:

```
prod <- read_excel("E:/DIR/prod_saltsnck.xls")
```

I just cannot seem to find the problem within the excel file, all 30 product excel sheets loaded in previously have worked without a problem.

EDIT:

[image]

It is a valid excel file but perhaps corrupt? I can open the excel file using excel without a problem.

EDIT 2:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252    LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] reshape_0.8.7   bindrcpp_0.2.2  forcats_0.3.0   stringr_1.3.1   purrr_0.2.5     readr_1.1.1    
 [7] tidyr_0.8.1     tibble_1.4.2    ggplot2_3.0.0   tidyverse_1.2.1 plyr_1.8.4      readxl_1.1.0   
[13] dplyr_0.7.6     magrittr_1.5
```

Comment: Yes the file exists, I am attaching a screenshot of the error I receive when I try to load it in using the R import dataset function.

Comment: which package do you use? I guess readxl? Did you try to update the package?

Comment: Yes the package is ` library(readxl)` I  am using version `readxl_1.1.0`

Comment: try readr::read_tsv

Comment: I get this error: `> prod <- read_tsv("E:/IRI Data/Academic Dataset External/parsed stub files/prod_saltsnck.xls")
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  ``<d0><cf><U+0871><e1>`` = col_character(),
  col_character(),
  A = col_character()
)
Error in read_tokens_(data, tokenizer, col_specs, col_names, locale_,  : 
  Evaluation error: Column 2 must be named.`

Comment: I have tried copying the excel data to a new excel document and saving it under the same name and extention and it still returns the same error.

Comment: sounds like it is no "real" excel: check this out https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/374

Comment: Saving the document as a .csv file allows me to import the data into R as a csv file. So I think it is a .csv file saved as a .xls file. It may have been deliberate. Now I have to work into the original function a method of "if not .xls, then read in .csv" :(

Comment: I have saved the apparant .xls file as a .csv which can then be read into R, however when I try to save the .csv to a .xls file again I obtain the same error.

Comment: Have you tried xlsx?

Comment: The problem with that is, I have many different .xls files, and this one seems to be the only one causing problems, all the others read in fine. The function is written to read in .xls files, I could go through an convert every .xls to .xlsx files but its just one file causing the problem.

Comment: Same error after downloading. I was able to read it with OpenOffice.org, export as CSV,  and then `read.csv` could read it it in. The "M" column was rather strange: `*STUBSPEC 1431RC                                                         00004  `. I'm guessing the parsing got messed up there.

Comment: I see the error says `Failed to open E:DIR/prod_saltsnck.xls`. This makes it look like the first slash might be getting misinterpreted. Try `read_excel("E://DIR/prod_saltsnck.xls")` with two slashes after E":

Comment: It was NOT a csv format originally. Look at the original with a text editor.

Comment: The file is saved as a .xls file but it does not appear to be a "true" .xls file. However it can be loaded into excel and then resaved as a .csv, I just cannot re-save it as a .xls file.

Comment: @42 what file do you see it as originally?

Comment: In my text editor there was a header that was not human-interpretable and a closing encoded section that had the word "Workbook". There was not a version number that was human readable, but it was neither Excel 95 nor Excel 97 format. I still wasn't able to get it to load with read_excel after taking out the extra spaces in the header line.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the first column L1 it has some funny characters before it. I saved the file as a .csv and then loaded it into R and in the R viewer you can see these special characters which should not be there. I removed them and tried to the file again as .xls but there problem continued. I think its either a problem with the first column or the column names.

Comment: Save as .xlsx seems working. My suggestion is save only this file as .xlsx and do some special case just for .xlsx files in your read function. BTW, have you tried other packages? I haven't had a chance yet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we are accessing the same data set as I also came across this issue with `prod_saltsnck.xls` and not the other product files. Perhaps you have already fixed the problem, nevertheless felt a response may be helpful. You could save the .xls file as .xlsx and then use `read_excel` function to read the file. Once you read the file, you will notice that there are several rows with `NA` cells. I suspect this could be the reason why `read_excel` did not work on .xls, though I do not have an explanation for why the function works on the .xlsx file. Hope this helps.